# GNU scientific lib : gsl_blas_dcopy vs gsl_vector_memcpy

Tags: c++, gsl

I am using the GNU scientific library and I was wondering what was the differences between those two function to copy a vector to another :
`gsl_blas_dcopy` and `gsl_vector_memcpy`

do you have any idea which one would be the fastest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GSL manual, section 8.3.6, it says

> However, it is useful to have a small number of utility functions
>   which do not require the full blas code. The following functions fall
>   into this category.
>
> `int gsl_vector_memcpy`

So both are basically the same. If you already need BLAS functionality, use `gsl_blas_dcopy`.

Rumors say a BLAS implementation for you specific CPU might be the fastest.